# R function for collapsing vectors down into summed groups of different sizes?

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have a long vector (adding a subset called original_data as a reproducible example) and I'd like to quickly collapse the vector down into consecutive elements summed up in groups, in this case groups of 4.  So for instance if I had the vector:

```
original_data <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

I would want this to collapse down to:

```
collapsed_data <- c(10, 26)
```

Since 1+2+3+4 = 10 and 5+6+7+8 = 26, and I'm summing together in groups of four.  I know my input vector will have length of a multiple of four, so I'm wondering how I can quickly collapse my vector down into summed groups of four, where the sums are done consecutively.

This approach works:

```
collapsed_data <- c()
 for (i in (1:(length(original_data)/4))) {
          collapsed_data[i] <- sum(c(original_data[1+4*(i-1)],
                                     original_data[2+4*(i-1)],
                                     original_data[3+4*(i-1)],
                                     original_data[4+4*(i-1)]))
  }
```

As the result is:

```
collapsed_data <- c(10, 26)
```

But it seems very inefficient.  Are there any better ways to do this that generalize to groups of different sizes (e.g. 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gl` to create a grouping variable of size 4, and use that in one of the group by functions

```
f1 <- function(vec, n) {
        n1 <- length(vec)
        unname(tapply(vec, as.integer(gl(n1, n, n1)), FUN = sum))
 }
f1(original_data, 4)
#[1] 10 26
f1(original_data, 5)
#[1] 15 21
f1(original_data, 6)
#[1] 21 15
```

---

Or use `%/%`

```
n <- 4
grp <- (seq_along(original_data)-1) %/% n + 1
unname(tapply(original_data, grp, sum))
```

---

Or with `rep`

```
grp <- rep(seq(length(original_data)/2), each = n,
             length.out = length(original_data))
```

Comment: Thanks!  The function f1 works perfectly for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Could use `by` with an index vector made from `rep(. ,each=4)`

```
as.vector( by(original_data, 
              INDICES = list(idx=rep(1:(length(original_data)/4), each=4)),
              FUN = sum) )
[1] 10 26
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tapply` option along with `ceiling`

```
> tapply(original_data, ceiling(seq_along(original_data) / 4), sum)
 1  2
10 26
```

or `colSums` + `matrix`

```
colSums(matrix(`length<-`(original_data, ceiling(length(original_data) / 4) * 4), 4), na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 10 26
```